# Get error node.js mongodb cannot read property 0 of null for records after successfull insert

Tags: node.js, nitrousio

I used db.collection.insert method to add a document in mongodb with function(err,records) callback. Though insertion succeeds (I checked on mongolab the record), records is null so that It throws error at records[0]._id

Is it a node.js bug on nitrous.io which I'm testing ?

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("successfully connected to the database");

        // Insert document in MongoDb Collection
                var document = {title:'test',category:'node.js'}

                db.collection('tut').insert(document, function(err,records){
                        //if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('inserted record id: ' + records[0]._id);
                  });
    }
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you're describing?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I've just updated

Comment: Just realized this is like the 4th time I've come to this same question... You earned an upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing the connection before the `insert` call completes.  Move your `db.close();` call inside the callback:

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("successfully connected to the database");

        // Insert document in MongoDb Collection
        var document = {title:'test',category:'node.js'}

        db.collection('tut').insert(document, function(err,records){
            //if (err) throw err;
            console.log('inserted record id: ' + records[0]._id);
            db.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't be frequently opening and closing your `MongoClient` connection pool.  It's generally best to open it during startup and leave it open until your app shuts down.