# node js mongo find last inserted

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having a hard time trying to find the last inserted element into mongo. I am using an example code I found and trying to make the query and display the item but I am getting an error. I understand I am suppose to do something like this.

```
db.collectionName.findOne({}, {sort:{$natural:-1}})
```

But this is what I have so far and it's not working.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

  var collection = db.collection('test');
  var doc1 = {'hello':'doc1'};
  var doc2 = {'hello':'doc2'};
  var lotsOfDocs = [{'hello':'doc3'}, {'hello':'doc4'}];

  collection.insert(doc1);
  collection.insert(doc2, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});
  collection.insert(lotsOfDocs, {w:1}, function(err, result) {});

  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs[0]);
  });

  db.close();
});
```

This is the error.

```
nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

I checked to make sure the database is not empty so I am not sure why it's returning null.

Comment: What is wrong with using the [**reverse order**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/#reverse-order) of the `$natural` operator: `collection.find({}).sort( { $natural: -1 } )toArray(..)` or simply `collection.find().sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(1)` to get the last document inserted?

Comment: i can't really test that because i can't get `collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs[0]);
  });` to work at the moment

Comment: any idea what is wrong with that? i am having problems with querying anything trying to console.log it at the moment

Comment: @ShinonChan Have you tried checking if the docs object is null before accessing its first element? What will show up in the console if you log the docs object?

Comment: Did you try logging `err` to see if you get an error message?

Comment: @Philipp I get `{ [MongoError: Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError' }` if i log the err

Comment: @VladZ. i get the `null` when i log the docs object

Comment: Do you have created timestamp field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a possible solution([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856892/get-error-node-js-mongodb-cannot-read-property-0-of-null-for-records-after-succe)) to your problem. It might be due to the fact that the database connection closes before the operations that you have issued finish.

You can fix it by including the `db.close()` call inside the `find` query.

```
 collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs[0]);
    db.close();
  });
```